# How will I show command prompt text in a richtextBox?

Tags: c#, process

I have this code which I want the value to show in a richtextbox.

```
Process proc = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
psi.FileName = "netsh.exe";
psi.Arguments = "wlan show profile";
proc.StartInfo = psi;
proc.Start();
```

Comment: [ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Set your [`UseShellExecute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.useshellexecute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to `false` and [`RedirectStandardOutput`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to `true` and you can use [`StandardOutput`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property of the `proc` and then you can iterate end of the stream.

From [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput%28v=vs.110%29.aspx);

> To use `StandardOutput`, you must set `ProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute`
>   to `false`, and you must set `ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput` to
>   `true`. Otherwise, reading from the `StandardOutput` stream throws an
>   exception.

Then you can assign which line do you want with `ReadLine` to your `RichTextBox`.

```
psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
psi.UseShellExecute = false;
```

then

```
while (!proc.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
{
   string line = proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
   // Assign this line to your RichTextBox.
}
```